# Force text to flow outside of a div, centered, with a different color

Tags: html, css

How do I get the text "textetxtetxt" to flow outside `innertext` equally - centered and overflowing left and right in `outerbox` - and change the text color in `outerdiv` to `#000` so it is visble against a `#fff` background color?

I have the `color` of `outerdiv` set to `#000`, but it doesn't effect the text color. And usign `margin: 0 auto;` on any of the divs doesn't effect the centering or overflow of the text in `innertext`. In the fiddle, `farouterdiv` has a background color of `#ddd` simply to make the text visible for now.

```
.outerdiv {color:#000;}
.outerbox {max-width:100px;background-color:#000;}
.innertext {color:#fff;font-size:36px;text-align:center;}
```

What I have now in the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amryh49y/5/

[image: What I have now]

What I want to be able to do, with the white text on the gray background to be black:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Centering using flexbox and Color difference with `mix-blend-mode`. Perhaps a simplistic demo but there are possibilities there. The "outerdiv" is not required in this scenario.

[**Mix-blend-mode@MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.farouterdiv {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.outerbox {
  max-width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.innertext {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="farouterdiv">

    <div class="outerbox">
      <div class="innertext">texttexttext</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice! That works well. Now, the nasty question :) I see that you used mix-blend-mode and that's not supported by IE. Do I need an IE fallback for this, even though it doesn't use images? I guess I can test it in Firefox dev tools with a user agent switch add-on.

Comment: Actualy, if I remove background-color: #ddd; from farouterdiv, the back text turns white and can't be seen. https://jsfiddle.net/amryh49y/11/

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` requires a background-color to interact with. in this case it's interacting with the bg color of `outerbox` not `farouterdiv`. For IE...you'd just have to find some other fallback I guess.

Comment: The back-ground color makes sense; I got it to work somewhat with a background image, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding another element:

```css
.outerdiv {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.innerdiv {
  width: 65px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  Hello World
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This has a few short-comings.  `transform` can have spotty support [if you need older browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (IE 8 and lower), and you may have some trouble with multi-lined entries.  Depending on your needs, though, both of these can be worked around.

If you'd like the off-color div to be non-centered it actually becomes a little easier

```js
// Javascript only here to get mouse-over effect.
// Text-coloration can be gotten with just the CSS

var outer = document.getElementsByClassName("outerdiv")[0];
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
var inner = document.getElementsByClassName("innerdiv")[0];

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var offset = outer.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var pos = e.clientX - offset
  inner.style.left = pos + "px";
  text.style.marginLeft = -pos + "px";
});
```

```css
.outerdiv {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.innerdiv {
  width: 65px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p><em>mouse over to see effect</em></p>
<div class="outerdiv">
  Hello World
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the `margin-left` of `.text` is the negation of the `left` of `.innerdiv` and the distance you want the black box from the left edge.